# BIOS update - Ubuntu 20.04 - Asus A320m-k

Tags: 20.04, bios, motherboard

```
sudo dmidecode -s bios-version
4022
```

Currently version of BIOS on my pc is 4022 but I saw the latest version is 5062. How can I update it?

Comment: Download the BIOS, write it to a flash drive and use ASUS Easy Flash feature in BIOS.

Comment: That works ^^. But updating your BIOS has nothing to do with the operating system expect for that you use Ubuntu to download a file and put it on a USB stick. See for instance https://www.gamersnexus.net/guides/1572-how-to-flash-bios-on-asus-board and do take note of the warnings.

Comment: I upgrade BIOS to the latest (5602), but right after that my Ubuntu won't boot. Blank screen, also keyboard, mouse doesn't working. Grub is not showing. I backup everything, but now I don't know what to do.

Comment: Sorry about your troubles. Do you even get the BIOS splash screen on your video monitor? Contact Asus Support at their web site, or via phone, asap. You could try removing AC power, remove the motherboard backup battery for 30 minutes, return the battery to its socket, replug AC, and retry. Try the CHAT function on the BIOS download web page.

Comment: @mmiroslav13 See https://www.asus.com/us/Motherboards/PRIME-A320M-K/HelpDesk_Knowledge/, and click the `BIOS/firmware` filter on left.

Comment: Nothing from above wasn't helpful. Still isn't working.